# Difference between "turn a profit" and "make a profit"

Tags: meaning, difference

I came across this idiom today.

> turn a profit
>
> To make money; to **make a profit** from a particular venture.
>
> From The Free Dictionary
>
> https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+a+profit

What is the difference between "turn a profit"  and "make a profit?

Take this example from the free dictionary.

> We're going to have to close the shop if we don't **turn a profit** again this quarter.

Is "turn a profit" and "make a profit" interchangeable here?

Comment: I think you have already answered your own question, In your quote from Free Dictionary the meaning of turn a profit is make a profit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference.  "Turn a profit" is more idiomatic/figurative, as it includes the image of your fortunes *turning*, from loss to profit, in the near future, but otherwise the usage is much the same.

> We're going to have to close the shop if we don't **make/turn** a profit again this quarter.

It even makes sense to use with an individual transaction

> I don't know how but, even in this market, he still managed to **turn/make** a profit on the sale of that old house.

Note: Because "turn" is metaphorical, when using it imagine a literal *change of direction*, as in the similar idioms "turn a corner" and "turn over a new leaf", so it's kind of a *decisive* moment. Once a business "turns" a profit in a given time period (or transaction) it doesn't normally "turn" back.

Although, as with any metaphor, it can be used creatively:

> We thought the business had **turned a profit** this quarter, only to have it **run into a brick wall** when we realized we hadn't set aside enough money to cover payroll taxes.